# How do I turn on popup blocker through terminal?

Tags: command-line, firefox

I'm trying to create a shell script to configure Firefox settings. I am currently trying to figure out how to turn on the popup blocker. Right now, I am adding the line `user_pref("dom.disable_open_during_load", true);` to the end of the prefs.js file. However, whenever I open Firefox, the popup blocker still isn't turned on. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please also check the MozillaZine URLs: 
1.  http://kb.mozillazine.org/Prefs.js_file

2. http://kb.mozillazine.org/Editing_configuration

that describe the best methods for editing preferences in Mozilla.

Also a user.js file may be an option as preferences in user.js will overwrite preferences in prefs.js with the user.js preferences.